# 2 divs inside another div but under text

Tags: html, css

I have a content div with some text inside, and 2 divs inside the content div placed next to each other.

I want the 2 child divs to display next to one another, but under the text, not next to it.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#first, #second {
  border: solid green 2px;
}
#content {
  border: solid purple 2px;
  display: flex;
  clear: both;
}
#second {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#first {
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">div id="content"
  <div id="second">div id="second"</div>
  <div id="first">div id="first"</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AthomicDestroyer/qt1p504k/) of how it looks like at now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See updated `JSFiddle`

```
#first, #second {
  border: solid green 2px;
}
#content {
  border: solid purple 2px;
  clear: both;
}
#second {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
#first {
    background-color: palegoldenrod;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#content::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qt1p504k/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was looking for, what the #content::after exactly does?

Comment: Your welcome, it's do `clear: both` because when you use `float` you need to use `clear`

Answer (score 1):

You can put both divs inside another div, like this:

```
<div id="content">
  div id="content"
  <div id="twoboxes">
    <div id="second">div id="second"</div>
    <div id="first">div id="first"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in yous CSS set the property `display` to `flex`. Here's the CSS:

```
#first, #second {
  border: solid green 2px;
}
#content {
  border: solid purple 2px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#twoboxes{
  display: flex;
}
#second {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#first {
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: But he added a new div too. :) Both ways work well for what you asked.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is to wrap your second and first div and change flex-direction on content div to column. ( I removed your padding: 500px as I have no idea what was the purpose of that. )

```css
#first, #second {
  border: solid green 2px;
}
#content {
  border: solid purple 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  clear: both;
}
#second {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}
#first {
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;  
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
div id="content"
<div class="main_content" >
  <div id="second">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
  <div id="first">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```